# convert string date to timestamp and timestamp to date with fixed result

Tags: php, date

I have an string date like this: `2015/12/20 13:58:59`

I try to convert timestamp:

```
$idate = $user->multiexplode(array("/"," ",":"),strip_tags("2015/12/20 13:58:59"));

//mktime( $hour , $minute , $second , $month , $day , $year , $is_dst );
$timestamp = mktime($idate[3],$idate[4],$idate[5],$idate[1],$idate[2],$idate[0]);
```

And now I try to convert real date:

```
echo 'new date: '.jdate('Y/n/j H:i:s',$timestamp);
```

Ok...it works but there is a problem!

according of time server,I get variable time.

for examle for location +1 GMT: 2015/12/20 14:58:59

for -1 GMT: 2015/12/20 11:58:59

I want for all server print `2015/12/20 13:58:59` again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `DateTime` class and it's methods to convert the date and time to unix timestamp. And use `strftime()` to convert the unix timestamp back to your desired format, like this:

```
$datetime = "2015/12/20 13:58:59";

// covert timestamp
$unixdatetime = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y/m/d H:i:s', $datetime)->getTimestamp();
echo $unixdatetime . "<br />";  // 1450616339

// now format the unix timestamp
$formatted_datetime = strftime("%Y/%m/%d, %H:%M:%S",$unixdatetime);
echo $formatted_datetime;  // 2015/12/20, 13:58:59
```

Output:

```
1450616339
2015/12/20, 13:58:59
```

Here are the references:

- [DateTime class](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php)
- [strftime()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strftime.php)

Answer (score 0):

Use this code.

```
<?php

$date = '2015/12/20 13:58:59';

//convert to timestamp
$timestamp = strtotime($date);

echo $timestamp;

//convert timestamp back to datetime
$date_again = date('Y/m/d H:i:s', $timestamp);

echo $date_again;

?>
```